# How to automate build process using python 3.4 and jenkins?

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

I havep python (v3.4) project on git repository and using Jenkins server for automate build process. 
I created a Job in Jenkins, job pulls new version of project from git and then execute two shell commands :

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

In console log i get this error :
....

```
nobounce.io 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing sample script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/sample'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to install the software on the server which isn't allowed. For one, you don't have the necessary permissions. And you probably shouldn't do it anyway: Imagine you have two jobs that create the package (development and bug fixes for the last release). Which one will you find in `/usr/local/bin/`? It would be pretty random.

Instead, you should build an egg which other people can then install and tell Jenkins to archive this as the build result.

If you have dependencies, you should look into `virtualenv`:

- https://jenkins-ci.org/content/python-love-story-virtualenv-and-hudson
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/shiningpanda-plugin

Comment: Thanks. How to install new install_requires then, and can Jenkins run project for me ?